# New Maven Project in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So I created a new maven project in IntelliJ. To run it I am using Smart Tomcat. Here you can see its settings.

[image]

When I run the project I get his log output.

```
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.16
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 4 2019 16:30:29 UTC
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.16.0
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.14.4
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/theodosiostziomakas/.SmartTomcat/emailservice/web-service-verification
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1,415] milliseconds
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 06, 2019 8:37:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [717] milliseconds
http://localhost:8080/web-service-verification
```

Finally I type http://localhost:8080/web-service-ve,rification in Chrome browser. However, I am getting that annoying 404 error. Should I make any additional settings in the project? I repeat it is a **Maven** and not a **Spring boot** project.

[image: 404 error]

You can clone and run the project if you want to see what I am talking about.

https://github.com/theo82/email-service

Comment: What is Smart Tomcat? Do you mean Apache Tomcat?

Comment: @Basil Bourque Yes. It is an Apache plugin for IntelliJ

Comment: You project runs fine on my machine with default Tomcat run configuration. Could you please try to disable custom plugins?